# Django Rest Framework - Nested Serialization not working

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

**model.py**

```
class Account(models.Model):
    name_Account= models.CharField(max_length=50, default='')
    fecha_nacimiento = models.CharField(max_length=150, default='')
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=150, default='')
    mail = models.CharField(max_length=150, default='')
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    rol_id = models.ForeignKey(Rol,on_delete=models.CASCADE, null =True)

class Reclamo(models.Model):
    nameReclamo= models.CharField(max_length=50, default='')
    rut = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='')
    numpoliza = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='')
    detalle_diagnostico = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='')
    account_id = models.ForeignKey(Account,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null =True)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    name_estado= models.CharField(max_length=50, default='Pendiente')
    num_claim= models.CharField(max_length=30, default=' ' ,blank = True)
```

**serializer.py**

```
class AccountSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Account
        fields = ('id', 'name_Account', 'fecha_nacimiento', 'phone', 'mail', 'user_id', 'rol_id')

class ReclamoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    name_Account = AccountSerializer(many=False) #read_only=True no return, no error 
    class Meta:
        model = Reclamo
        fields = ('id','nameReclamo','rut','numpoliza','detalle_diagnostico','account_id','date','name_estado','num_claim', 'name_Account')
```

**error**

> Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field
>   `name_Account` on serializer `ReclamoSerializer`.
>       The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Reclamo` instance.
>       Original exception text was: 'Reclamo' object has no attribute 'name_Account'.

I have tried different examples, but I cannot return what I hope

Comment: The issue is that Reclamo object has no name_Account attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The property `name_Account` does not exist. You have to point to `account_id` as that is the `ForeignKey` to the `Account` model.

```
class ReclamoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    account_id = AccountSerializer(many=False)
    class Meta:
        model = Reclamo
        fields = ('id','nameReclamo','rut','numpoliza','detalle_diagnostico','account_id','date','name_estado','num_claim')
```

Comment: name_Account  is inside "", transcription error, I modify the extract of the question code

Comment: Hi, @FcoBad. I've edited the answer. could you please check it out?